# Link from content script to options page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to link to options page from content script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html):

> **Referring to extension files**
>
> Get the URL of an extension's file using chrome.extension.getURL(). You can use the result just like you would any other URL.

So `chrome.extension.getURL("options.html");` should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

just add to manifest.json

> "web_accessible_resources": ["options.html"]

and this will work from contentscript.js

> window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("options.html"));

Comment: This is the solution if you are getting an about:blank page, just add it to the web_accessible_resources

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, for opening the options as a new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "options/index.html"
})
```